# Calculate mean from previous N rows in the column

Tags: python, pandas

For dataframe `df` below, I would like to find the mean of the last 3 values in the `sales` column for each row, naming the result in a new column `Mean_lst_3` as shown below, what's the best way to do it?

```
    STK_ID  RPT_Date  TClose   sales       Mean_lst_3
0   000568  20060331    3.69   5.975       NaN
1   000568  20060630    9.14  10.143       NaN
2   000568  20060930    9.49  13.854       NaN
3   000568  20061231   15.84  19.262       9.99 (= mean([5.975, 10.143, 13.854]))
4   000568  20070331   17.00   6.803       14.42(= mean([10.143, 13.854, 19.262]))
5   000568  20070630   26.31  12.940       13.31(= mean([13.854, 19.262, 6.803]))
6   000568  20070930   39.12  19.977       ...
7   000568  20071231   45.94  29.269       ...
8   000568  20080331   38.75  12.668       ...
9   000568  20080630   30.09  21.102       ...
10  000568  20080930   26.00  30.769       ...
```

Comment: Hi @cs95 I think you might have misunderstood my question, CMIIW, I was looking for the last 3 values based on the current row instead of the entire dataframe.

Comment: Ah, I got the wrong impression because of U11 forward's answer. Are you looking for `df['sales'].rolling(3).mean().shift()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `tail`:

```
print(df['sales'].tail(3))
```

Comment: It returned `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'tails'`. CMIIW, I'm looking for last 3 values based on the current row, isn't `df.tail()` getting the same last 3 rows for the dataframe?

Comment: @nilsinelabore Edited my answer

Comment: Updated the question, `tail` doesn't appear to be what they are looking for.

Comment: @cs95 Yes that's true